# WPF - Modern UI (Metro) Charts: RadialGaugeChart and more doens't work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, charts

I installed the Modern UI (Metro) Charts library and added a reference to my project. The following XAML Code should work, but it doens't!

```
<Window x:Class="T.MainWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:T.Properties"
                  xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart;assembly=De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart"
                  Title="T" BorderThickness="0" Height="716.467" Width="948.939" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" Loaded="MetroWindow_Loaded" WindowTitleBrush="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Path=Farbe, Mode=TwoWay}">
<Grid>
     <chart:RadialGaugeChart ChartSubTitle="Population in percentage"  
                             ChartTitle="Countries by population" 
                             Background="White">
            <chart:RadialGaugeChart.Series>
                <chart:ChartSeries 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
            DisplayMember="Name" 
            ValueMember="Count" />
            </chart:RadialGaugeChart.Series>
        </chart:RadialGaugeChart>
</Grid>
```

```
public ObservableCollection<Diagramm> _Diagramm { get; set; }

    public class Diagramm
    {
        public string Typ { get; set; }

        public int Zahl  { get; set; }        
    }

    private void MetroWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _Diagramm = new ObservableCollection<Diagramm>();
        _Diagramm.Add(new Diagramm() { Typ = "Gefahrene Dienste", Zahl = gefahren });
        _Diagramm.Add(new Diagramm() { Typ = "Nicht gefahrene Dienste", Zahl = ngefahren });
    }
```

But `PieChart` works!

I get a error, that

> `RadialGaugeChart` is not defined!

How can I fix it? Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a closing `</chart:RadialGaugeChart>` tag in your XAML. Here's a working sample:

XAML:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication222"
    xmlns:MetroChart="clr-namespace:De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart;assembly=De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart" 
    x:Class="WpfApplication222.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <MetroChart:RadialGaugeChart ChartSubTitle="Population in percentage"  
                                 ChartTitle="Countries by population" 
                                 Background="White">
        <MetroChart:RadialGaugeChart.Series>
            <MetroChart:ChartSeries 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
                SeriesTitle="My Population Series"
                DisplayMember="Name" 
                ValueMember="Count" />
        </MetroChart:RadialGaugeChart.Series>
    </MetroChart:RadialGaugeChart>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyData> Data { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Data = new ObservableCollection<MyData>
        {
            new MyData {Name="Country 1", Count = 10 },
            new MyData {Name="Country 2", Count = 25 },
            new MyData {Name="Country 3", Count = 40 },
        };
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer! I get this error: "The name "RadialGaugeChart" does not exist in the Namespace "clr-namespace:De. TorstenMandelkow. MetroChart; assembly=De. TorstenMandelkow. MetroChart"." :/ Can you send me the link, where the download of the library is, that you use...?

Comment: This could be a typo in your XAML. Please post your full XAML that is causing such error, not only bits and pieces.

Comment: Your XAML is ok. Try installing it through **NuGet** instead of downloading it from Codeplex.

Comment: I always get the error, but I can compile it? The designer does not work but I can compile, it's weird...

Comment: You can go to **Tools/Choose Toolbox Items** menu and add it, so the designer will work.

Comment: What exactly is the DLL you have under **References** in your project?

Comment: The DLL is the "De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart.dll"

Comment: Maybe also important by starting the designer of the window: "It was tried to load an Assembly of a network address what would have led in former versions from. NET Framework for explaining of the Assembly than Sandkastenassembly. In this version from. NET Framework the CAS directive is not activated normally, hence, this loading process can be dangerous. If you do not intend to provide a Sandkastenassembly by this loading process, activate the loadFromRemoteSources counter. You find further information under "http://go. microsoft. com / fwlink/? LinkId=155569"."

Comment: I would say start a fresh project and install it from Nuget. I have it from both Codeplex and Nuget. For this particular sample i posted I'm using the one i installed from Nuget.

Comment: Did you add it to the `Toolbox` as mentioned before?

Comment: If you installed it from Nuget, the DLL should be under a `packages` folder within your project structure. Add that DLL to your `Toolbox`.

Comment: You can only have one at a time. I have both in my computer but the project uses only one, in my case the Nuget one.

Comment: Also a problem ist, that the code (added) doens'nt work? Also your and my code....

Comment: Sounds like your environment is broken... I would repair your VS install, restart the machine, etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but do you have another code, where I can make a MySQL-Command an then I add something in the list (ObservableCollection)?

Comment: Perhaps you should post a separate question for the MySQL command. If i can't help you, someone else will. Did you solve your problems with the chart?

Comment: Yes, I did... But the only problem, that I have now, is, that the Designer doesn't work... The code work but the designer says, that it doens't know this "element"... :/